# Sentences starting with “in what must be a first”?

Tags: meaning-in-context, idioms

> The opening of Ken Loach’s film *Riff-Raff* in New York casts doubt on Winston Churchill’s observation that the United States and Britain were two countries separated by common language. **In what must be a first,** an entire British film has been given sub-titles to help Americans cut through the thick stew of Glaswegian, Geordie, Liverpudlian, West African and West Indian accents.
> <sub>Source: Excerpt from the *Guardian,* quoted in [*The Penguin Guide to Punctuation* (pp. 5–6)](http://www.doko.vn/tai-lieu/the-penguin-guide-to-punctuatio-791682)</sub>

Please help me understand the meaning of “in what must be a first” in the above passage.

Comment: _For what is (probably) the first time_

Comment: Thanks Adam.So does it mean "For the first time" in history.I am confused with the "In" preposition in above phrase.Could you please elaborate the purpose of "In" here. Does it mean "for the first time in itself"?

Answer (score 3):

In English, we often say something is "a first" to to note an unusual or unprecedented event.

> My dog didn't finish her dinner tonight.  That's a first.
>
> I wrote typed an entire page without noticing the caps lock was on.  That's a first for me.
>
> I am really proud of my sister getting straight A's.  That's a first for her.

The sentences above constitute three "firsts."  In fact, you might tally them in that way.

> I didn't finish my dinner today, then I sat down and typed a whole page without noticing the caps lock was on.  That's *two firsts* in one night.

Imagine this, then:

> An entire British film has been given English sub-titles.  That has never been done before.  It's a first.

---

Now how do we get the "in" out front?  Think of the these "firsts" as being like abstract acts. More examples might be  *"In a display of generosity"* or *in a fit of rage*, or *in a drunken stupor.*...

*A first* could also be an abstract act like these.  *"In what was a first for me, I wrote this answer without using bold face."*  The *in* situates the second clause within the context of the abstract act described in the first clause.

I realize this isn't a hard and fast grammatical explanation - I am trying to demonstrate a continuum of constructions from some with which you may be familiar  to the one you are asking about.

Answer (score 1):

It's an idiomatic expression - not easily analyzed. *In* refers (probably) to "time" or "occasion" (which is omitted from the end of the expression):

"In what must be a first (time)"

It would make more sense with *for* instead of *in*, and *the* instead of *a*, but that's what makes it an idiom.